# Automate loading a table into SDE

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

How can I automatically load a table stored on a network share into SDE when the original table is edited?

Environment is ESRI 10.1 ArcSDE on SQL Server.
Preference for python or existing GP tools.
Table would be a csv or xlsx.

Any ideas, info, or pointers would be helpful.

Comment: I know it isn't the question you asked, by why don't you just stop people from updating the table?  SQL Server has a security for just that reason.

Answer (score 2):

This could be implemented as a multiple steps process:

1. You could run a Python script that would evaluate a .csv or .xls file and compare it to the latest modified version you have loaded into an SDE geodatabase.
2. If there any changes found, then you would convert the source file into a table by using [Table to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Table_to_Table/001200000027000000/) (csv) or Excel to Table (since 10.2 only) ([xls](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000001w000000)) GP tools (both of them of course available from Python too via [arcpy site package](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_ArcPy/000v000000v7000000/)). The output data could be stored in_memory or as an intermediate data somewhere on the disk.
3. You run [Truncate Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000016z000000) GP tool on the SDE geodatabase table and then [Append](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Append/001700000050000000/) to move the created earlier table rows into an existing table.